# can't compile jar with gcj: undefined reference to main

Tags: gcj

I developed my java project with eclipse and built a runnable jar.
Then I tried to use gcj to compile that jar.

```
stefan@api-1:/Sbox/Software/executables$ gcj --classpath=Sbo
xSpeakerDependent.jar --main=SboxInterface SboxSpeakerDependent.jar -o Test
/tmp/ccpTssYV.o: In function `main':
ccIqdepF.i:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `SboxInterface::class$'
collect2: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
```

But SboxInterface is the only class that has a main-method and I also put this information while creating the runnable jar in eclipse.

What can I try? I'm a bit lost what is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCJ Linking Error: Says error: undefined reference to 'main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990605/gcj-linking-error-says-error-undefined-reference-to-main-collect2-error-ld)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the class is in the jar and that you are passing the fully-qualified class name to --main.  These are the two most common errors.